# Face match with TensorFlow.js between image stored in DB and real-time webcam image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tensorflow.js

I am not familiar with TensorFlow.js. I am creating a module in React and Node.js with TensorFlow.js.

I am able to capture image first and convert image to `Tensor` with this code:

```
const imageDataURL = this.canvasRef.current.toDataURL('image/png');
const b = Buffer.from(imageDataURL, 'base64');
```

getting result:

```
Uint8Array(297020) [117, 171, 90, 138, 102, 160, 123, 250, 103, 129, 182, 172, 123, 174, 34, 84, 19, 145, 195, 66, 134, 130, 128, 0, 0, 3, 82, 82, 17, 20, 128, 0, 0, 150, 0, 0, 0, 125, 2, 1, 128, 0, 0, 56, 84, 20, 245, 0, 0, 8, 0, 18, 81, 16, 85, 30, 23, 187, 47, 90, 100, 201, 50, 92, 73, 90, 59, 132, 94, 89, 199, 119, 67, 71, 136, 185, 32, 185, 43, 50, 34, 28, 25, 143, 243, 63, 190, 198, 68, 144, 40, 211, 192, 136, 57, 242, 242, 43, 59, 20, …]
```

And with this code:

```
const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(this.videoRef.current);
```

result is:

```
Tensor {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(3), dtype: "int32", size: 921600, …}

dataId: {id: 4811}
dtype: "int32"
id: 3541
isDisposedInternal: false
kept: false
rankType: "3"
scopeId: 6508
shape: (3) [480, 640, 3]
size: 921600
strides: (2) [1920, 3]
isDisposed: (...)
rank: (...)
__proto__: Object
```

I need to convert the first image to `Tensor`, after that I need to match the face with real-time webcam: is person matching, true or false.
I am very confused on how to write the logic.

Comment: There is insufficient information to assist you. What model are you using for face recognition? How is the image stored on the database?

Comment: Actually, I am tensorflow-model/blazeface model. I am only able to detect face with realtime webcam. Please, give me the solution. 1st I have to store user face image in any format in database. 2nd I have to recognization that image with realtime webcam and identitfy the user match or not. Can you please call me or whatsapp on my contact number +91NineNine92FourFourFour6Nine9. It will be very helpfull for me.

Comment: Look up Siamese Networks for this task, BlazeFace alone is not sufficient you would need to crop the faces detected by it then pass them along to another model to compare with the one in the database.

Comment: @NeerajKumar Did you got the solution?

Comment: No, you have any solution?